# help with Content provider

Tags: android, sql, provider

I've been working on this content provider for a few days now, and I've been looking for answers online.

Could someone please clarify for me.

I am trying to transfer my android sqlite DB from one app to another, and I want to use the content provider.  I have it written out, but it is not working.

My question is, does the content provider and the CONTENT_URI go in the same package of the source app?  And then I call to it from the other app?

Comment: What do you mean by "transfer[ing the] DB from one app to another" -- accessing data of app A from app B using A's ContentProvider?

Comment: Also, have you [defined your ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html) in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: And how exactly is it "not working"?

Comment: @Phillipp Yes, I'm sorry for my wording. That is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yes it is defined in the manifest also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, content provider and the CONTENT_URI can go in the same package of the source app. For the other app to call to it, you will have to have the same CONTENT_URI and then, the content resolver will do the rest for you.