# accessing the content provider

Tags: android, sql, provider

If I have a content provider and CONTENT_URI in in application A, and it is also in the manifest.  How do I call to it from application B?

Do I need to write the code in class that holds my sqlite database?  Or do I need to make a whole new class and call to the provider from there?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: **may be duplicate** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348900/help-with-content-provider

Answer (score 0):

You may register Activity B to accept URIs according to their nature.

To do so, you add the following "intent-filer" section to Activity B in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity android:name="ACTIVITY B PATH">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="THE MIME TYPE TO ACCEPT" />
       </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This will register Activity B to accept VIEW actions with URIs that math the MIME type.

Then, when Activity A runs the following code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI)); 
 activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Activity B will be activated automatically and you can read the URI by calling getIntent().getData() from your onCreate() method.

You may choose different ACTIONS (VIEW, EDIT, INSERT...) and DATA TYPES (MIME, SCHEMA, PATH...) that is most suitable to your needs.